# How to kill the entire application except one activity in Android?

Tags: android

I have a design of activities like this

I have one main activity and 5 subactivities (from 1 to 5).

From main activity I can call any of these subactivities and when I call the subactivity I am not finishing the main activity because I may need to comeback here at a later. **So the main activity is running in the background**

But when I enter the subactivity, I am making call. I am dispatching call activity to perform call operation. But **I want to kill all the activities except that "call activity**". the main activity is still in the background. How to kill it and all other activities which are active?

Comment: You should not worry about killing Activities. Let Android do it.

Comment: i should close my applcation when my task is finished,right? so i want to know how to close the application.after calling is done the main activity screen is still displaying, which should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might also be worth taking a look into the different launch modes for activities. For example, you could use the `singleInstance` on your 'root' activity to always return to that the same instance - meaning Android will not push another Activity instance on the back stack when you call `startActivity(...)`, but pop everything inbetween and deliver the intent to the already existing instance. Alternatively, `singleTask` will give you similar, yet slightly different behaviour.

Have a read through the [Task and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) article on Android's developer website. It gives a nice overview of and explains the different launch modes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments, not activities. This will allow you stay within one activity for all main and sub tasks, and simply call `finish()` when you are done.

Another idea would be to `finish()` the main activity when you launch the child, and when you need to go back to the main activity from the child, you start the main activity again, with some context passed in an intent, as necessary, so it can pick up in the right place ... So you only ever have on activity on the stack, and if it `finish()`s there's nothing left.

Another idea would be to have a receiver listening in the main activity that can `finish()` the main activity. Then in the sub activities, send an intent to the main activity telling it to quit when the sub activity quits.

Comment: i am thinking of implementing second approach. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: but how to use fragments, because i need different layouts in  different activities i dont know how to use fragments...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to Kill entire Application

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but i dont wat to kill entire application , i have one activity named "call activity" which should not be killed

Comment: it doesn't kill the application
it just go to home
the application will still be in the task manager

Answer (score 0):

You can check the activity stack from activity manager run a loop and see if the current activity is you activity or not otherwise kill it.

Code is as follows

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(this.getApplication().getPackageName());
```